# Magento 2 tries to load old theme on category pages

Tags: database, category, magento2.2, theme

I'm using **Magento 2.2.3** and after switching from the custom theme (Infortis - Ultimo) to Luma, all category pages are still displaying the Ultimo theme. The rest of the website displays using Luma so the problem is just with category pages. I've uninstalled the custom theme but the category pages still try to load it and give the error...

```
Exception #0 (LogicException): Unable to load theme by specified key: '6'
```

'6' is the ID of the old theme. The new theme's ID is '2'. I don't know where in the database there's a reference causing categories to try using the old theme on just category pages.

The order I've tried to do this is...

- Changed theme to Luma in **Content > Configuration**
- Removed the rows containing umm_ from ***eav_attribute*** table (as recommended)
- Removed the custom theme entries from the ***theme*** table
- Removed the theme files from **app/code** & **app/design**
- Flushed the cache
- Removed var/view_preprocessed (and all the other var/cache files)
- Removed pub/static/frontend/*

I've tried other combinations too but nothing has worked.

Comment: Could you please check once Category configuration. Is there any custom theme applied or not ?

Comment: The database was holding onto the old ID in just one value column in catalog_category_entity_varchar. The core_config_data entry was the correct one (for Luma). I found the problem and answered it below yesterday with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a fix for this problem. In the database look in the **eav_attribute** table and get the **attribute_id** for **custom_design** in the **attribute_code** column (e.g. 60). Once you have this number look in the table **catalog_category_entity_varchar**. Look in **attribute_id** column for the **custom_design** value (e.g. 60). All instances of the number had NULL in the **value** column except one. This was still showing 6. I changed the value to NULL and flushed the Magento cache and now the category pages are using the new theme.

Comment: it's not working with my situation. Do you have any solution else? I changed in category config but still error on front-end

Answer (score 0):

I my case the main category design was assigned to the older theme,
I just changed it to the newer theme and without clearing cache on the frontend design displayes as expected.

[image]